# How do I get the Git menu to appear in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: github, visual-studio-2019

Visual Studio is connected to GitHub in **Manage Connections** > **GitHub**

I have **GitHub Extensions for Visual Studio** installed.

In Preview Features, the following are checked...

- **GitHub Action support in Publish**
- **New Git user experience**

I am running Visual Studio in Admin mode.

I have restarted the compute and Visual Studio multiple times.
I have a local repo opened.

I have been able to connect the project to GitHub and commit code already, but now I am unable to.

I can see the menu in the **Extensions** > **Customize Menu** dialog (see attached).

Still, my repo is not connected to GitHub and I don't see the menu item.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case there was no "Add to Source Control" in lower right corner. File > Clone repository... also did not help. But I was able to connect to remote repository via VS Get Started window.

Comment: The `Add to Source Control` is appearing only when a project/solution is opened in the Visual Studio.

Answer (score 6):

Can you see "Add to Source Control" in lower right corner of Visual Studio window? If yes, click it and then click Git. In my case, Git menu appeared after this action.